# How to make AltGr act like Alt on Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keyboard-layout

On M10 or Aquaris when connecting USB keyboard, how to set <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> to be the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson, there is none selected in Settings -> Language&Text -> External Keyboard. When I try to select anything and close the settings - it goes back to zero layouts selected. Keyboard acts like US intl. I'm testing Alt in terminal app by erasing words with Alt+Backspace.

Comment: I don't know much about Ubuntu Touch, but on desktops `us+intl` reserves <AltGr> for accessing level 3 and 4 symbols on respective key.